# Temporarily block google maps gesture recogniser

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios, uipangesturerecognizer

Context:

Google maps controller which has a slide menu on it's right and left.

Problem:

When the user opens the left or right slide menu the google map slides together with the menu which is an unwanted user experience.

Question:

How can I block google maps gesture recogniser when I slide my menus and enable it again when my slide has been finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour can be controlled by setting the value of scrollGestures.

Example:

```
//in case you want to disable GMSMapView from receiving your dragging
mapView.settings.scrollGestures = false
//in case you want to enable GMSMapView to receive dragging gestures again
mapView.settings.scrollGestures = true
```

Setting this value reflects immediately on the behaviour of the GMSMapView.